Quartz net configuration with service provider
I would like to configure Quartz net by using dependencies from the service provider, concretely I would like to access the SecretClient in order to retrieve the connection string from key vault.
Quartz Net provides a fluent API for configuration purposes however I cannot access any dependencies in it, nor do I see a way to extend it so that options are preconfigured:
services.AddQuartz(op =>
{
    op.UsePersistentStore(pso =>
    {
        pso.UsePostgres(apo =>
        {
            apo.ConnectionString = ...; // <-- This I would like to inject either from KeyVault if *Development*, *Test* or *Production*, or have a hardcoded value from appsettings if *LocalDevelopment*
        });
    });
});

I tried adding the QuartzOptions as an option as so:
services.AddOptions<QuartzOptions>()

and then adding configuration in appsettings.{environment}.json as so:
{
    "Quartz": {
        "quartz.dataSource.myquartzstore.provider": "Npgsql",
        "quartz.dataSource.myquartzstore.connectionString": "connection-string-for-environment"
    }
}

This works but forces me to hardcode the connection string in the appsettings, however I would like to manage this connection string in key vault only and retrieve it from there based on the secret name as so:
public class PostgreDbConnectionProvider(SecretClient secretClient, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment, IOptions<PostgreSqlOptions> postgreSqlOptions) : IPostgreDbConnectionProvider {

 ...

 public string GetConnectionString()
 {
     var isEnvironmentLocalDevelopment = hostEnvironment.IsEnvironmentLocalDevelopment();

     var secretIdentifier = postgreSqlOptions.Value.ConnectionStringSecretIdentifier;
     var connectionString = postgreSqlOptions.Value.ConnectionString;

     var resolvedConnectionString = isEnvironmentLocalDevelopment
         ? connectionString
         : secretClient.GetSecret(secretIdentifier).Value.Value;

     return resolvedConnectionString;
 }

 ...

}

How I tried to use this to configure Quartz was by using PostConfigure on QuartzOptions, and this did change QuartzOptions but Quartz still used default values instead
services.AddOptions<QuartzOptions>()
    .BindConfiguration("Quartz")
    .PostConfigure<IPostgreDbConnectionProvider>((op, postgreDbConnectionProvider) =>
    {
        var connectionString = postgreDbConnectionProvider.GetConnectionString();

        //var jobStoreTxTypeName = typeof(JobStoreTX).AssemblyQualifiedNameWithoutVersion();
        var systemTextJsonObjectSerializerTypeName = typeof(SystemTextJsonObjectSerializer).AssemblyQualifiedNameWithoutVersion();

        // Could be modified to increase performance
        op.Add("quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow", "0");
        
        // Could increase performance, depends on count of simultaneous jobs, on average, and maximum, also on system resources
        op.Add("quartz.threadPool.maxConcurrency", "10");

        // Listeners are ommitted - they are invoked via Quartz events

        // Trigger firing history loggin configuration is left default - 
        // https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/configuration/reference.html#sample-configuration-of-logging-trigger-history-plugin

        op.Add("quartz.dataSource.myquartzstore.provider", "Npgsql");
        op.Add("quartz.dataSource.myquartzstore.connectionString", connectionString);

        //op.Add("quartz.jobStore.type", jobStoreTxTypeName);

        op.Add("quartz.serializer.type", systemTextJsonObjectSerializerTypeName);
    });

When I access QuartzOptions via DI, I get the correct values
public class AATestJobsController(
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory,
    IOptions<QuartzOptions> quartzOptions,
    ILogger<AATestJobsController> logger)
    : ApiControllerBase(...)
{

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync()
{
    var options = quartzOptions.Value; // <-- values are correct here
    var jobKey = JobKey.Create("jobId", "groupId");
    var jobBuilder = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleLoggerJob>();

    var jobDetail = jobBuilder
        .WithDescription($"Job created at {DateTimeOffset.UtcNow}")
        .WithIdentity(jobKey)
        .UsingJobData(new JobDataMap
        {
            { "x", 10 },
            { "y", 20 },
            { "z", 30 }
        })
        .DisallowConcurrentExecution()
        .RequestRecovery()
        .StoreDurably()
        .PersistJobDataAfterExecution()
        .Build();

    var cronExpression = MyCustomSchedule.CreateDaily(06, 17, 1).Value.ToString();

    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1))
        .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression)
        .Build();

    var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    try
    {
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "Could not schedule");
    }

    return Ok();
}

The await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger); does not write the job to the database even though QuartzOptions has values which should instruct Quartz to persists jobs and triggers there.

You can check whether your application database connection is correct and whether there is any relevant error information.

It is correct, because I can connect when these settings are specified in appsettings.json but cannot connect when the same configuration is specified as part of the options.PostConfigure
